# Linear System of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

Would you mind telling me how do we use Matrix Algebra to get a general solution of the system:

$$x'=-{\delta}^{2}x+y+\delta z$$
$$y'=-x-{\delta}^{2}y+\delta z$$
$$z'=-\delta z$$

where $\delta$ is a parameter.

Comment: Can you write this system into matrix form? And then diagonalize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We rewrite this as:

$$x' = A x = \begin{bmatrix} -\delta^2 & 1 & \delta \\ -1 & -\delta^2 & \delta \\ 0 & 0 & -\delta \\ \end{bmatrix}x$$

We find the eigenvalues of this matrix using $|A - \lambda I| = 0$, which gives us:

$$-\delta - \delta^5 - \lambda - 2 \delta^3 \lambda - \delta^4 \lambda - 
 \delta \lambda^2 - 2 \delta^2 \lambda^2 - \lambda^3 = -(\delta+\lambda) ((\delta^2+\lambda)^2+1) = 0$$

This gives us the three eigenvalues:

$$ \lambda_1 = -\delta,~ \lambda_2 = -\delta^2 + i, ~\lambda_3 = -\delta^2 - i$$

Now, you can find the eigenvectors and then write the solution for $x(t)$.

The three eigenvectors are:

- $v_1 = \left(\dfrac{\delta (\delta^2- \delta +1 )}{\delta^4-2 \delta^3 + \delta^2+1}, -\dfrac{-\delta^3 +\delta^2+\delta}{\delta^4-2 \delta^3 + \delta^2+1},1\right)$
- $v_2 = (-i, 1, 0)$
- $v_3 = (i, 1, 0)$

Also note, that $z$ is a decoupled equation and you can solve for it straight off, substitute back into the $x'$ and $y'$ and reduce this to a $2 x 2$ system, which is much easier to work with when dealing with parameters.

Comment: Thanks! @Amzoti, but I got up to this step and the hard part is to get the eigen-vectors and you know to get the matrix $P^{-1}$ where P is the matrix formed by these three linearly independent eigen-vectors. Is there any way to get this $P^{-1}$?

Comment: When you find the eigenvectors, $P$ is just formed by their columns and then we can find $P^{-1}$. Given that we have three distinct eigenvalues, we know we can diagonalize the matrix from this system. To find the eigenvectors, all you will you do is substitute a (you only need to do twice, since we have a complex conjugate one) eigenvalue to solve $[A-\lambda_i I]v_i$ and use Gaussian Elimination. Regards

Comment: @Algebra: I added the eigenvectors for you to work through. Regards

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks for the support and Happy Sunday!

Comment: I woke up an hour earlier than I thought I did! (Return to Central Standard Time here in WI!) So I gained an hour! (Wish I had remembered when I was still half-asleep this morning - I would have slept the extra hour!)

Comment: @amWhy: I wish we would end this hour change craziness (some locales do not do it cause it throws our system off!

Answer (score 0):

What you have here is a linear homogeneous system of ODEs with constant coefficients.  Form the matrix $A$ given by 
 \begin{array}{ccc}
-\delta^2 & 1 & \delta\\
-1 & -\delta^2 & \delta\\
 0 & 0 & -\delta 
 \end{array} 
and find the eigenvalues of $A$ as the roots of characteristic polynomial of $A$ (i.e. the determinant of the matrix $xI-A$). For each eigenvalue you will have to find a corresponding eigenvector.  (In general you'll need to find a basis for the complete eigenspace, and in some cases generalized eigenvectors, but in your case the multiplicities are all one, so you'll just need a single eigenvector for each eigenvalue.)  The solution to the system can then be expressed in terms of the eigenvalues and eigenvectors.  (See your textbook for the formulas, but be careful, as two of the eigenvalues in this example may very well be complex.)  Hope this is enough  of a hint.